# Why does Haskell not allow two data constructors to share "Const" and other defined data attributes?

Tags: haskell

```
data Prop = Const Bool
          | Var Char
          | Not Prop
          | And Prop Prop
          | Imply Prop Prop
```

I am implementing the above data contructor with a minor addition,

```
data Prop = Const Bool
          | Var Char
          | Not Prop
          | Or Prop Prop
          | And Prop Prop
          | Imply Prop Prop
```

When I try to make another data contructor below that uses the previously defined constructor,

```
data Formula = Const Bool
          | Var Prop
          | Not Formula
          | And Formula Formula
          | Or Formula Formula
          | Imply Formula Formula
```

I get this error:
"Multiple declarations of 'Const'"

The same error follows with `Not`, `And`, `Imply`, and `Or`. Why does Haskell not allow this?

Comment: Think about what the type of `Const` would be if this was allowed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Haskell doesn't allow this because it would be ambiguous. The value constructor `Prop` is effectively a function, which may be clearer if you ask GHCi about its type:

```
> :t Const
Const :: Bool -> Prop
```

If you attempt to add one more `Const` constructor in the same module, you'd have two 'functions' called `Const` in the same module. You can't have that.

Comment: Note that it's probably not an *entirely* unsurmountable problem, as such an overloaded constructor has a lot in common with a class method. Whether any such implementation would be worth the trouble is another question.

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat horrible, but will basically let you do what you want:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms, TypeFamilies, ViewPatterns #-}

data Prop = PropConst Bool
          | PropVar Char
          | PropNot Prop
          | PropOr Prop Prop
          | PropAnd Prop Prop
          | PropImply Prop Prop

data Formula = FormulaConst Bool
          | FormulaVar Prop
          | FormulaNot Formula
          | FormulaAnd Formula Formula
          | FormulaOr Formula Formula
          | FormulaImply Formula Formula

class PropOrFormula t where
    type Var t
    constructConst :: Bool -> t
    deconstructConst :: t -> Maybe Bool
    constructVar :: Var t -> t
    deconstructVar :: t -> Maybe (Var t)
    constructNot :: t -> t
    deconstructNot :: t -> Maybe t
    constructOr :: t -> t -> t
    deconstructOr :: t -> Maybe (t, t)
    constructAnd :: t -> t -> t
    deconstructAnd :: t -> Maybe (t, t)
    constructImply :: t -> t -> t
    deconstructImply :: t -> Maybe (t, t)

instance PropOrFormula Prop where
    type Var Prop = Char
    constructConst = PropConst
    deconstructConst (PropConst x) = Just x
    deconstructConst _ = Nothing
    constructVar = PropVar
    deconstructVar (PropVar x) = Just x
    deconstructVar _ = Nothing
    constructNot = PropNot
    deconstructNot (PropNot x) = Just x
    deconstructNot _ = Nothing
    constructOr = PropOr
    deconstructOr (PropOr x y) = Just (x, y)
    deconstructOr _ = Nothing
    constructAnd = PropAnd
    deconstructAnd (PropAnd x y) = Just (x, y)
    deconstructAnd _ = Nothing
    constructImply = PropImply
    deconstructImply (PropImply x y) = Just (x, y)
    deconstructImply _ = Nothing

instance PropOrFormula Formula where
    type Var Formula = Prop
    constructConst = FormulaConst
    deconstructConst (FormulaConst x) = Just x
    deconstructConst _ = Nothing
    constructVar = FormulaVar
    deconstructVar (FormulaVar x) = Just x
    deconstructVar _ = Nothing
    constructNot = FormulaNot
    deconstructNot (FormulaNot x) = Just x
    deconstructNot _ = Nothing
    constructOr = FormulaOr
    deconstructOr (FormulaOr x y) = Just (x, y)
    deconstructOr _ = Nothing
    constructAnd = FormulaAnd
    deconstructAnd (FormulaAnd x y) = Just (x, y)
    deconstructAnd _ = Nothing
    constructImply = FormulaImply
    deconstructImply (FormulaImply x y) = Just (x, y)
    deconstructImply _ = Nothing

pattern Const x <- (deconstructConst -> Just x) where
    Const x = constructConst x

pattern Var x <- (deconstructVar -> Just x) where
    Var x = constructVar x

pattern Not x <- (deconstructNot -> Just x) where
    Not x = constructNot x

pattern Or x y <- (deconstructOr -> Just (x, y)) where
    Or x y = constructOr x y

pattern And x y <- (deconstructAnd -> Just (x, y)) where
    And x y = constructAnd x y

pattern Imply x y <- (deconstructImply -> Just (x, y)) where
    Imply x y = constructImply x y

{-# COMPLETE Const, Var, Not, Or, And, Imply :: Prop #-}
{-# COMPLETE Const, Var, Not, Or, And, Imply :: Formula #-}
```

If https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/issues/8583 were ever done, then this could be substantially cleaned up.